# I want to run a group by query after I get a result of a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a basic understanding of SQL, (not good in JOINS),
so here's the deal I'm writing a script in which I want to get the total count of the recent status of my transactions.

i.e at the end of the day what is the count of status, how many were buy, sell, paid, etc.

for example:

```
transaction_reference  status   time_stamp
123av                   buy     2020-07-23 06:06:17
123av                   sell    2020-07-23 06:06:18
124av                   buy     2020-07-23 06:06:23
124av                   sell    2020-07-23 06:06:38
125cv                   buy     2020-07-23 06:06:24
125av                   buy     2020-07-23 06:06:14
125ad                   paid     2020-07-23 06:06:14
```

I got a query to get the last status of each transaction,

```
SELECT
  count(DISTINCT transaction_reference),transaction_reference, MAX(time_stamp),status
FROM
  transactiontable
WHERE
    time_stamp >= '2020-07-23 06:00:00' and time_stamp <= '2020-07-23 16:00:00'
GROUP BY
transaction_reference;
```

Hence I get is below result:

```
transaction_reference  status   time_stamp
123av                   sell    2020-07-23 06:06:18
124av                   sell    2020-07-23 06:06:38
125cv                   buy     2020-07-23 06:06:24
125av                   buy     2020-07-23 06:06:14
125ad                   paid    2020-07-23 06:06:14
```

This result is giving me the recent status of each transaction_reference,
now I want to count the status,
*status has other values also apart from buy and sell.

That is the required output:

Status Count
buy    2
sell   3
paid   1

Since I'm weak in "JOIN",
My first solution is to take this into a temp table, and then run the group by command.

other is use inner join.

If this can be done by using joins, can anyone tell me how?

or in simple words can I run query on query,

like

```
Select count(*),C from table1
where
(select * from table1 where a='12')
group by C;
```

Comment: Your first query is broken.  The `select` and `group by` are inconsistent in the columns they select.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think mysql just does an auto max in this case

Comment: @Hogan . . . Actually, it does not and it is documented as dangerous.  You are correct about SQLite -- although the construct should be avoided there too.

Comment: Hi, No this is not broken,

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I wasn't defending it -- clearly that it lets this user do this type of construct is adding to their confusion

Answer (score 0):

Just group by status too... like this:

```
SELECT
  count(*), transaction_reference, MAX(time_stamp),status
FROM
  dxl_payment.BARCLAYS_TRANSACTION 
WHERE
    time_stamp >= '2020-07-23 06:00:00' and time_stamp <= '2020-07-23 16:00:00'
GROUP BY transaction_reference, status
```

now you will get a row for each status type and the count for those types

to get a count of each status do this:

```
SELECT
  count(*), status
FROM
  dxl_payment.BARCLAYS_TRANSACTION 
WHERE
    time_stamp >= '2020-07-23 06:00:00' and time_stamp <= '2020-07-23 16:00:00'
GROUP BY status
```

the patern to get a count based on another group is to use sum -- like this:

```
SELECT
  count(DISTINCT transaction_reference),transaction_reference, MAX(time_stamp)
  sum(case when status='a' then 1 else 0 end) as count_a_status,
  sum(case when status='b' then 1 else 0 end) as count_b_status,
  sum(case when status='c' then 1 else 0 end) as count_c_status
 
FROM
  transactiontable
WHERE
    time_stamp >= '2020-07-23 06:00:00' and time_stamp <= '2020-07-23 16:00:00'
GROUP BY
transaction_reference;
```

Comment: Hi, I believe this will be the same as my query, as now count is only 1 for each transaction once i put max(time_stamp).

Comment: @AdityaKumar -- see above I changed the count statement to have a meaningful result

Comment: This will give me no of counts for each transaction_reference wrt status.

Comment: isn't that what you want @AdityaKumar?

Comment: Nope, I want total count of each status. Since, my each transaction can  have more than 1 status, so my earlier query is providing me the recent status of each transaction. Now i want to calculate total counts, of how may were sell, buy,paid.

Comment: @AdityaKumar still not sure what you want but I added two tings that might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last status on each day using a time comparison and correlated subquery:

```
SELECT bt.*
FROM dxl_payment.BARCLAYS_TRANSACTION bt
WHERE bt.time_stamp = (SELECT MAX(bt2.time_stamp)
                       FROM dxl_payment.BARCLAYS_TRANSACTION bt2
                       WHERE bt2.transaction_reference = bt.transaction_reference AND
                             DATE(bt2.time_stamp) = DATE(bt.time_stamp)
                      ) AND
      bt.time_stamp >= '2020-07-23 06:00:00' AND
      bt.time_stamp <= '2020-07-23 16:00:00'
```

To get the distribution of statuses, aggregate:

```
SELECT bt.status, COUNT(*)
FROM dxl_payment.BARCLAYS_TRANSACTION bt
WHERE bt.time_stamp = (SELECT MAX(bt2.time_stamp)
                       FROM dxl_payment.BARCLAYS_TRANSACTION bt2
                       WHERE bt2.transaction_reference = bt.transaction_reference AND
                             DATE(bt2.time_stamp) = DATE(bt.time_stamp) AND
                             bt2.time_stamp >= '2020-07-23 06:00:00' AND
                             bt2.time_stamp <= '2020-07-23 16:00:00'
                      ) AND
      bt.time_stamp >= '2020-07-23 06:00:00' AND
      bt.time_stamp <= '2020-07-23 16:00:00'
GROUP BY bt.status;
```

For performance, you want an index on `BARCLAYS_TRANSACTION(transaction_reference, time_stamp)`.

Comment: This one's timing out !

Comment: @AdityaKumar . . . .Both an appropriate index and filtering in the subquery will help.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Taking very much time in my server and timeout after 30 sec

Answer (score 0):

Re-using you query:

```
SELECT
  count(DISTINCT transaction_reference),transaction_reference, MAX(time_stamp),status
FROM
  transactiontable
WHERE
    time_stamp >= '2020-07-23 06:00:00' and time_stamp <= '2020-07-23 16:00:00'
GROUP BY
transaction_reference;
```

It will be wrapped as follows:

```
select
  /* remove DISTINCT below to get pure count/total */
  count(DISTINCT status) as status_count,
  sum(case when status = 'buy' then 1 else 0 end) as buy,
  sum(case when status = 'sell' then 1 else 0 end) as sell,
  sum(case when status = 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) as paid
from (
  SELECT
    count(DISTINCT transaction_reference),transaction_reference, MAX(time_stamp),status
  FROM
    transactiontable
  WHERE
      time_stamp >= '2020-07-23 06:00:00' and time_stamp <= '2020-07-23 16:00:00'
  GROUP BY
  transaction_reference
) your_query;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did is spent 2hrs learning JOINS and here you go,
This is working 100%.

Documenting if someone might find this helpfull.

```
select count(distinct a.transaction_reference),a.status from transactiontable as a ,
(
SELECT
  count(DISTINCT transaction_reference),transaction_reference, MAX(time_stamp) as time_stamp,status
FROM
   transactiontable
WHERE
    time_stamp >= '2020-07-24 16:00:00' and time_stamp <= '2020-07-25 16:00:00'
GROUP BY
transaction_reference) as b where a.transaction_reference=b.transaction_reference  and  a.time_stamp=b.time_stamp 
group by a.status;
```

This is giving me the exact count.